# How do I display all power plans in Windows 7 notification area?

Tags: windows-7

By default, only the most recently used plan as well as "balanced" are available. How do I display all 3 default power plans? I'd like to avoid third party programs if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Battery Care installs malware along with it. You can opt out (although not obviously at first glance). I would discourage users from installing software that bundles malware. The author gets barely enough to buy a beer per year from that stuff and it only serves as a distribution point for malware and spyware. It needs to end.

[Here's an alternative](http://powerschemeswitcher.codeplex.com/) that doesn't bundle any malware.

Answer (score 6):

Shameless plug:
[Power Buddy](https://github.com/PerfectlyCromulentLtd/PowerBuddy/releases)

Power Buddy is a very lightweight system tray application that allows you to switch between all the defined power plans.

No malware.  No junk.

**Full Disclosure:  I am the author of this project.**

Comment: This was simple, and automatically populated with all my power plans into a tray context menu.  Good suggestion

Comment: Warning: [a user reported](//superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/649224) his experience that Windows Defender reported a Trojan in the installer for Power Buddy.

Comment: @G-Man **Update:** The trojan false-positive has been fixed: https://github.com/PerfectlyCromulentLtd/PowerBuddy/issues/12

Answer (score 3):

Windows 7 has no natural settings to show more than 2 power plans in the system tray. However, you can create shortcuts or hotkeys to switch between your power plans. How-to Geek has a nice article about how to do that: [Create a Shortcut or Hotkey to Switch Power Plans.](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/create-a-shortcut-or-hotkey-to-switch-power-plans/)

One of the users in a forum having the same question as you says that this solution is perfect; but each time he ran the shortcut, the command prompt popped up for a second. To prevent this he created a small script. You can see the related post [here](http://forum.notebookreview.com/microsoft-windows-7/417165-more-than-just-2-power-plans-battery-tray-icon-popup-3.html#post5315312).

There is also a Windows sidebar gadget which can do what you want. It's called Power Scheme and can be downloaded from this [page](http://gallery.live.com/liveItemDetail.aspx?li=e0040b09-c1c8-4ad0-b2a4-a3efc8fa850f&bt=1&pl=1).

Although you avoid 3rd party solutions, there is a tool called [Power Plan Assistant for Windows® 7](http://www.powerplan7.com/features.htm) which can do the job as well.

[image]

Comment: Note that Power Plan Assistant is nagware. After one week of use, the software disables itself, and you're required to download a new version from the website and to install it again. You have to repeat this every week as long as you keep using it.

Comment: A good alternative I've found is BatteryCare, at http://batterycare.net/en/download.html

Comment: Battery Care has already been suggested as an answer to the question: http://superuser.com/a/162697/13567

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [Battery Care](http://batterycare.net/en/index.html), a freeware tool that does more than allowing you to easily change the power plans (Power Saver, Balanced and High Performance) . See this [Battery Care review](http://answers-tips.blogspot.com/2010/05/optimize-usage-and-performance-of.html)

Comment: Could you write a bit more about it, especially in comparison with Power Plan Assistant?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the shortcut key <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> which will bring up the mobility center; then you may choose the power plan you want. very simple!!

Comment: this is also what i use

Comment: This is 4 strokes/click + a large menu select. compared to in Win10:  6 clicks using the stock battery guage notification/tray icon.  So this is not much of a comparative savings in Win10.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Power Plan Assistant](http://www.techspot.com/downloads/4883-power-plan-assistant-for-windows-7.html)

> Searching for 'show all 3 power plans in tray software'? Congratulations, you just have found a comprehensive solution. Power Plan Assistant for Windows 7 is an ultimate manual / automatic power plan switcher and a compact (yet very informative) system Power icon replacement. It's the multiple award-winning, the world's smartest power management tool. 
>   Blockquote

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw in a late update to this, [Power Scheme Switcher](http://powerschemeswitcher.codeplex.com/), under the MIT license with source code available from the same place. Built in C# on Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to this an other question, on how to create your own Power Scheme switcher menu, using only Windows built-in features :

https://superuser.com/a/1631250/711015

That way you can show and have access to switch to any number of schemes.