# How to bring more than 2 power options, in the System Tray Power Tool?

Tags: windows-7, power-management, notification-area

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I display all power plans in Windows 7 notification area?](https://superuser.com/questions/160866/how-do-i-display-all-power-plans-in-windows-7-notification-area)

While using the Laptop, I frequently change my power options, based on the applications that I am using, but while changing these options, its a pain as only 2 power options are listed in the tool at System Tray.

Any Idea, how to list all power options, on the system tray?

Comment: exact duplicate of [How do I display all power plans in Windows 7 notification area?](http://superuser.com/questions/160866/how-do-i-display-all-power-plans-in-windows-7-notification-area)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Battery Care, a freeware tool that does more than allowing you to easily change the power plans (Power Saver, Balanced and High Performance) . See this [Battery Care review](http://answers-tips.blogspot.com/2010/05/optimize-usage-and-performance-of.html)