# Windows - See more than two powerplans in the battery-menu in the tray

Tags: windows-8.1, taskbar, user-interface

On clicking the battery icon in the tray, the menu shows the current power plan and the last used power plan. Is it possible to make the menu show more than two power plans?

Answer (score 1):

Windows by default doesn't display more than one power plan on the tray, so the easiest way is to use a 3rd party software.

[Power Scheme Switcher](http://powerschemeswitcher.codeplex.com/)

This is a very simple utility that exposes an icon in the system tray and allows you to quickly change the Power Plan Scheme from there.

[image]

Also see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/160866/how-do-i-display-all-power-plans-in-windows-7-notification-area).